# html form action="." not submitting to self, but instead submitting to root directory

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form in one of my pages and I want to make it submit to the same page. I am doing this:

```
<form method="POST" action=".">
```

But when I submit the form it submits to the root directory of my site instead of to the same page the form is on.

I know that the form is being submitted because I tried temporarily changing the method to GET and when I submitted the form, the URL showed the get variables.

Why is the form not submitting to the current page?

If it's relevant, I'm using PHP with xampp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

Comment: or write the php filename under action!

Comment: @user2207792 yeah of course I realize I can do that, I just wanted to make this shorthand work

Comment: @Juampi that worked! thanks! I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when stack lets me

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
```

I'm a newbie though so if Juampi's answer works too , I'd go with it.

Comment: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html. See the exploits section.